# Change Connection string at runtime

Tags: asp.net

I have 2 projects.
One is WebSite Project Second is WCF Project.
My Connection String is in WCF Project.

Now, I reference WCF Project dll to Website Project.
Now, I want to host website project,So I required to change connection string Path of wcf Project.

How can i change connection string of wcf project at runtime?

Comment: Just add the `connectionStrings` section of the config file of wcf project to `web.config`

Comment: you cant change it if you are using a dll